# Installing Tomato on WRT54gl v4.30.x

Tags: router, firmware

Basically I'm looking to install tomato on my router. I've looked on the website and noticed that it says to only use WRT54gl's that have version 1.x on them. Currently my router has v4.x. In order to get tomato installed will I have to downgrade my router and then switch firmware or is it possible to just install tomato like it is? Does anyone have any experience with something such as this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken. Version on tomato site means your Linksys *hardware* version, not software, so you can't downgrade it. Here is a good link on how to determine hardware version of your Linksys router: http://www.slideshare.net/techdude/how-to-identify-the-hardware-version-of-linksys-wrt54g-router